# Applying "SetTitleTextAttributes" to a push back button

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

So I have vc A & vc B. When I perform a push segue from A to B automatically creates a back button. This is great but I want to change the text color of this button to black with SetTitleTextAttributes.

From reading other questions relating to this I learned that you have to edit the back button that will appear in vc B in vc A. Somthing like this:

**On vc A:**

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem.SetTitleTextAttributes (textAttrButton, UIControlState.Normal);
```

On some questions they say to put this in the viewWillAppear others say just before you perform a segue to vc B. In both instances I get the following error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is on vc B:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option is to use use `UIAppearance` for this. Works for all `UIBarButtonItems` in the entire app, but requires iOS.

`UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new TextAttributes { TextColor = UIColor.Black }, UIControlState.Normal);`

Comment: ok, so what would be the place to put this pice of code? ViewDidLoad still gives the same error.

Comment: `NavigationItem` is null inside your controller's `ViewDidLoad`? Is the controller inside a `UINavigationController`? It doesn't sound like it is.

Comment: Not sure what u mean but i have a navigationcontroller so if i perform a push segue a back button automaticly shows.

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Can you use `UIAppearance` for this? Works for all `UIBarButtonItems` in the entire app, but requires iOS 5 - `UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes` - I generally always use this when styling navigation bars and items.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm and I dont have to change every button.If you update your answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the attrbutes by using the appearance proxy of the navigation bar back button item. I'm nt sure if or how that works in C# though.